# How can I make this into a seamless texture

Tags: texturing, uv, image

I am making a model of mcu black panther but it has a lot of intricate details. For this part I am trying to make the cloth part of him a seamless texture I can unwrap on the model. I highlighted the part I'm talking about.
[image]

Comment: You're on the wrong StackExchange site for a question like this. Try the [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) site, they may be able to help you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about general imaging techniques and not blender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various tutorials on using programs such as Photoshop to create seamless textures. Unfortunately, I do not know how to do this off the top of my head at the moment, but you can use Photoshop (as I said) or Gimp.